# windows missing by dual monitors in Fedora 15/Gnome 3

Tags: fedora

I've set up dual monitor display in Fedora 15/Gnome 3.

However, the windows failed to display on my secondary monitor.(mouse can drag these missing windows on secondary monitor, I just cannot "see" them) How to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you have this second monitor configured? can you by chance post a screenshot of your display settings?

Answer (score 0):

I found something **similar** [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/trouble-with-window-position-559754/). The following is a quote from the site that could be helpful.

> 1) install gconf-editor ( yum install gconf-editor ).
>
> 2) run
>   gconf-editor either via a terminal or else from Applications -> System
>   Tools -> Configuration Editor
>
> 3) navigate to apps --> compiz -->
>   general --> allscreens --> options and edit the active_plugins node on
>   the right
>
> 4) put "place" in the series right after "resize" (with
>   commas and such to keep them seperate)
>
> 5) disable & re-enable desktop
>   effects.